# How to modify Python DataClass inside map(lambda: )

Tags: python, lambda, python-dataclasses

I want to modify a dataclass(dataclass_json) in a map/lambda. With dictionaries you can perform a dict.update({"key": "value"}) within a lambda, but how does one update a dataclass's value without:

```
MyDataClass.name = "class name" # this works outside a lambda
```

(Example below is the incorrect syntax I know)

```
repositories_list: List[MyDataClass]
_ = list(map(lambda repository: repository.name = my_func(repository), repositories_list))
```

Of course I can't just use =, so how's this done?

Comment: If It's Only doable inside a separate function I guess I can concede to that, but would be much more preferable to have my actions taken explicitly shown in this lambda.

Answer (score 1):

You can access [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr), the function that does the actual work during an attribute assignment, directly:

```py
list(map(lambda r: setattr(r, "name", my_func(repository)), repositories_list))
```

This pattern is not dataclass-specific, it works with any python object.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with replace from dataclasses

```
from dataclasses import replace
repositories_list = list(map(lambda repository: replace(repository, name=my_func(repository)), repositories_list))
```

Comment: that creates a copy of every object in that list though, so changes won't propagate between all of them, and it's not exactly space- or time-efficient.